# C#: Combining for(each) loops to efficient code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, loops, razor

This is part of my timetable code

Two questions :

1. How can I prevent having to loop through the times, and then the roombookings to check if it exists in the given time slot. Is there a way of just saying "for this time, is there a match(s) from this list and what is its Id"
2. Is there anyway I can set the outer td to class bgred, rather than a span. (Note that there may be multiple bookings in a timeslot, hence having the td out of the foreach loop.)

```
<tr>
    <th></th>

        @for (int i = 9; i <= 17; i++)
        {
        <th>@i:00</th>
        }
</tr>

    @foreach (var RoomNo in ViewBag.Rooms)      
    {

        <tr>

            <th>@RoomNo</th>

           @for (int i = 9; i <= 17; i++)
           {
               <td>
               @foreach (var roombooking in ViewBag.RoomBookings)
               {
                   DateTime DateCheckStart = DateTime.Parse(ViewBag.Date.ToShortDateString() + " " + i.ToString() + ":00");
                   DateTime DateCheckEnd = DateTime.Parse(ViewBag.Date.ToShortDateString() + " " + i.ToString() + ":59");
                   if (DateCheckStart < roombooking.EndDateTime && DateCheckEnd > roombooking.StartDateTime && roombooking.RoomNo == RoomNo)
                   {
                     <span class="bgred"> @roombooking.RentalNo</span>
                   }
               }
               </td>
           }
        </tr>

     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
 <table>
<tr>
    <th></th>

        @for (int i = 9; i <= 17; i++)
        {
        <th>@i:00</th>
        }
</tr>

@{ List<MyLibrary.MyRoomOccupancy> RoomBookingsTemp = ViewBag.RoomBookings;}

@foreach (var RoomNo in ViewBag.Rooms)
{
    <tr>
        <th>@RoomNo</th>

       @for (int i = 9; i <= 17; i++)
       {             
           DateTime DateCheckStart = DateTime.Parse(ViewBag.Date.ToShortDateString() + " " + i.ToString() + ":00");
           DateTime DateCheckEnd = DateTime.Parse(ViewBag.Date.ToShortDateString() + " " + i.ToString() + ":59");

           var sublist = (from RoomOcc in RoomBookingsTemp where DateCheckStart < RoomOcc.EndDateTime && DateCheckEnd > RoomOcc.StartDateTime && RoomOcc.RoomNo == RoomNo select RoomOcc);


           if (sublist.Count() > 0)
           {
              @Html.Raw("<td class= \"bgred\">");

            }
           else {
               Html.Raw("<td>");
           }

           foreach (var roombooking in sublist)
           {
               if (DateCheckStart < roombooking.EndDateTime && DateCheckEnd > roombooking.StartDateTime && roombooking.RoomNo == RoomNo)
               {
                  @roombooking.RentalNo
               }
           }
           @Html.Raw("</td>");

       }
    </tr>

}


</table>
```

What this does is it loops through onlyt he

Comment: OOO. THat doesnt remove the for, but it essentially do a similar thing of meaning I dont have to loop through the whole data list. Hence reducing computation significantly! And it solves the problem of the td class! Genious my friend! Thanks for that. Your description is missing. :)

Comment: Your code doesnt work in the MVC3 environment. Using the concept Im trying to create the same effect.

Comment: Sorry I didn't test it, I was just guessing for the most part. I'll let you fix my syntax errors :P

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this

```
@foreach (var roombooking in ViewBag.RoomBookings.Where( /* in range */ ))
```

So that you can remove your first for loop

Comment: But then how would it know what table cell it is looking in? I.e. which time slot. The foreach Room, for each time defines the table, then the unnecessary loop it looping through the data?

Comment: you are not using I for anything though, other than you see if it's in range. and you're not passing the time slot id to the html.

Comment: My fault, I left the table header out of the code. Each loop of I creates a new TD, which slots under the relevant timeslot.

Answer (score 1):

You should be filtering your data in the controller and only passing relevant data to the view.

You can use linq to objects in the controller, or even better filter data in the database.

Comment: I want to display it all, in the relevant slot. If I filter it before hand, all the data wont be avalible